# Scroll to Section through <svg> click with offset below Navigation

Tags: angular, svg

**Description**

I would like to use an  graphic to click to an section within an html page. Unfortunately Angular seems not to support fragment routing which are placed within the . Therefore I search for a solution to scroll with an offset to the html section. At the moment I am able to scroll to the upmost position within my page. Unfortunately I could not find a way to set an offset which helps me to scroll below the navigation bar. Who could support me with this issue? I would jump from the svg-click to the section on my page.

Please see the code snippets below, I use Angular Bootstrap and would be happy to solve this issue. So take into consideration that the scrolloffset can not been used as it is only working with fragment routes.

With best regards,
To

**Inline svg:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Left side navigation-->
        <div class="col-xl-2 d-none d-xl-block pr-0 fixed-top">
            <!--Change of inline svg image-->
            <!--Export from AI with -->
            <!--SVG: class="img-fluid img-top-margin" -->
            <!--set id in svg graphics which can be manipulated via css-->
              <svg class="img-fluid img-top-margin" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 250 500">
                <title>leistungen_nav_left</title>
                <text transform="translate(86.86 38.11)" font-size="24" fill="#003750" font-family="Ubuntu">Digitalisierung</text>
                <line x1="126.06" y1="106.55" x2="126.06" y2="163.4" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4"/>
                <line x1="126.06" y1="195.64" x2="126.06" y2="251.65" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4"/>
                <line x1="126.06" y1="284.43" x2="126.06" y2="339.24" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4"/>
                <line x1="126.06" y1="372.96" x2="126.06" y2="428.29" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4"/>
                <line x1="126.06" y1="74.96" x2="126.06" y2="47.33" fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4"/>
                <g id="KonzeptionStyle">
                  <circle id="Circle" cx="126.06" cy="90.25" r="8" fill="#f8f9fa" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4"/>
                  <text transform="translate(146.15 97.83)" font-size="20" fill="#d3d3d3" font-family="Ubuntu"><tspan letter-spacing="-0.02em">K</tspan><tspan x="12.16" y="0">on</tspan><tspan x="35.44" y="0" letter-spacing="-0.02em">z</tspan><tspan x="44.48" y="0">eption</tspan></text>
                  <a xlink:href="#Konzeption"><rect x="112.05" y="72.93" width="137.95" height="35.12" rx="4.49" fill="#fff" opacity="0"></rect></a>
                </g>
...
</svg>
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
// Router configuration for router fragment links
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash : true,
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'disabled',
  scrollOffset: [0, 80],
};
```

**html-section**

```
<section id="Software"></section>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[*|href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).attr('xlink:href');
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem above with the usage of css, there I set the top position to -100px.

```
    :target {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px; 
  visibility: hidden;
}
```